# How to Skip typescript linter "null-checking", because it has been already done in "assert" function

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have created an "assert" function, It check for a condition and throws an appropriate error if condition fails. It exists their for the sake of removing if/else from the code-base.

```
export function assert(predicate : boolean, err: any) {
    if(!predicate) throw err;
}
```

I'm doing "null-checking" in the assert function, but tslint is showing me "Object is possibly 'null'."

```
public async run(params: LoginUserDTO, context: any): Promise<LoginUserResponse> 
{

    await this.validateInput(params);
    const {email, password} = params;

    const user: User | null = await this.userRepository.getByEmail(email);

    // I'm doing "null-checking" here
    assert(!!user , new EmailOrPasswordDidNotMatchError());
      
    // Linter is showing warning here, "user is possibly 'null'."
    assert(user.isEmailVerified , new EmailNotVerifiedError());

    // Linter is showing warning here, "user is possibly 'null'."
    const passwordMatched = await Password.compare(password, user.password);

    // Linter is showing warning here, "user is possibly 'null'."
    assert(passwordMatched , new EmailOrPasswordDidNotMatchError());
    
    // Linter is showing warning here, "user is possibly 'null'."
    const loginTokens = await this.getLoginTokens(user);

    return new LoginUserResponse(loginTokens.accessToken , loginTokens.refreshToken);
}
```

is there any way to deal with the situation? or
how can i write custom tslint rule to skip "null-checking" if i have an assert before?

UPDATED :
Thanks to @OlegValter, i found a way to handle the issue. Here is the updated "assert" function, i added assertion singnature

```
function assert(predicate : boolean, err: any) : asserts predicate {
    if(!predicate) throw err;
}
```

Comment: well... You are doing nothing in your function. You need an assertion signature if you want to narrow types like that. https://tsplay.dev/NVnK5N

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks for the help, it worked out for me.

Comment: this, of course, works only TS 3.7+. Official docs, are, as usual, a [good read](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)